# How many samples do I need to prove that a classification algorithm is better than another?

Tags: classification, confidence-interval, sampling, many-categories

I have two algorithms A and B, used to automatically classify each of N elements into K categories, N and K both being in the millions. Neither A or B is perfect, but it is relatively easy for a human to do the classification, or put another way, to select which one of the algorithms A and B did a better job for a given element.

I want to show that algorithm A is better than B, but am not sure how to approach this problem. As A and B most often say the same thing, I want to focus on the cases where they don't. My question is now, how many elements do I need to check to show (with a certain degree of confidence) that A is better than B? Or put another way, given a random sample from where A and B differ where n_a elements were correctly classified by A, and n_b elements were correctly classified by B, how likely is it that A is better than B?

Comment: One idea is (for example) to simulate 10 dataset with N element and K categories, and for each of them and  algorithm compute the percent of right classified element and then compute a mean over the 10 dataset. Then you simulate another 10 dataset and compute the mean of right estimated element on the 20 datasets. You go on until the mean is in some sense stationary,i.e. doesn't change any more of the degree of change is too small. You can try this method for different choice of N and K and see it this two parameter affect the performance of the two algorithm

Comment: The input is fixed (I cannot generate new elements to be classified), as is the set of categories K. I can examine the results of the algorithms for a specific subset of N, but not restrict the number of categories for that case.

Comment: If you select a subsamples $N^*<N$, with yours algorithm can you classified the $N-N^*$ observations not used in the agorithm?

Comment: @niandra82, the two algorithms have already processed every algorithm in N and I can in fact not run them on any set smaller than N - classification is dependent on the whole input set, not a pure function from an element to a category. What I can do is manually analyse any subset of N and decide which one of the two algorithms (if any) picked the correct category for each item.